# What's wrong with my code?

Tags: ruby

```
    def encrypt(string)
      alphabet = ("a".."b").to_a
      result = ""
      idx = 0
      while idx < string.length
        character = string[idx]

        if character == " "
          result += " "
        else
          n = alphabet.index(character)
          n_plus = (n + 1) % alphabet.length
          result += alphabet[n_plus]
        end
        idx += 1
      end
      return result
    end
    puts encrypt("abc")
    puts encrypt("xyz")
```

I'm trying to get "abc" to print out "bcd" and "xyz" to print "yza". I want to advance the letter forward by 1. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Rather than just asking what is wrong, please post what outcome you are expecting and what you are seeing.

Comment: You can also do this a lot more easily with `string.each_char` and `character.ord - 'a'.ord` to get the index of a character. For ciphers it's actually just one line: use [`tr`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-tr).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All I had to do was change your alphabet array to go from a to z, not a to b, and it works fine.

```
def encrypt(string)
  alphabet = ("a".."z").to_a
  result = ""
  idx = 0
  while idx < string.length
    character = string[idx]

    if character == " "
      result += " "
    else
      n = alphabet.index(character)
      n_plus = (n + 1) % alphabet.length
      result += alphabet[n_plus]
    end
    idx += 1
  end
  return result
end
puts encrypt("abc")
puts encrypt("xyz")
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve the issue, that I think is simpler, personally, is to use [`String#tr`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-tr):

```
ALPHA = ('a'..'z').to_a.join             #=> "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
BMQIB = ('a'..'z').to_a.rotate(1).join   #=> "bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza"

def encrypt(str)
  str.tr(ALPHA,BMQIB)
end

def decrypt(str)
  str.tr(BMQIB,ALPHA)
end

encrypt('pizza') #=> "qjaab"
decrypt('qjaab') #=> "pizza"
```

Comment: `tr` is the way to go for simple ciphers. It's a little peculiar in how it works, but it does one thing very, very well. The performance is usually vastly beyond any `gsub` equivalent. Your translation variable `BMQIB` is also amusing.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been answered, so here are a couple of more Ruby-like ways of doing that.

**Use [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a hash**

```
CODE_MAP = ('a'..'z').each_with_object({}) { |c,h| h[c] = c < 'z' ? c.next : 'a' }
  #=> {"a"=>"b", "b"=>"c",..., "y"=>"z", "z"=>"a"}
DECODE_MAP = CODE_MAP.invert
  #=> {"b"=>"a", "c"=>"b",..., "z"=>"y", "a"=>"z"}

def encrypt(word)
  word.gsub(/./, CODE_MAP)
end

def decrypt(word)
  word.gsub(/./, DECODE_MAP)
end

encrypt('pizza')
  #=> "qjaab"

decrypt('qjaab')
  #=> "pizza"
```

**Use `String#gsub` with [Array#rotate](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-rotate)**

```
LETTERS = ('a'..'z').to_a
  #=> ["a", "b", ..., "z"]

def encrypt(word)
  word.gsub(/./) { |c| LETTERS.rotate[LETTERS.index(c)] }
 end

def decrypt(word)
  word.gsub(/./) { |c| LETTERS.rotate(-1)[LETTERS.index(c)] }
end

encrypt('pizza')
  #=> "qjaab"

decrypt('qjaab')
  #=> "pizza"
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you for this, I will keep this in mind.

Comment: wouldn't `tr` be a lot simpler than `gsub` in this case?

Comment: @philomory, I used `gsub` so that I could use a hash with it. Using `tr` is a good idea, but I don't see how it's simpler than `gsub`.  The only problem with `tr` is that it's a bit messy here. Either you convert the string to an array of characters, apply `tr`, then join, or you make a copy of the string and replace characters in place. In any event, please put up an answer showing how it could be used.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I added my own answer showing `tr` usage, you don't need to convert the string to an array in order to use `tr`, `tr` is a String method.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you don't want to take up that memory storing the alphabet you could use character codings and then just use arithmetic operations on them to shift the letters:

```
def encrypt(string)      
  result = ""
  idx = 0
  while idx < string.length
    result += (string[idx].ord == 32 ? (string[idx].chr) : (string[idx].ord+1).chr)
    idx += 1
  end

  result
end
```

Other strange thing about ruby is that you do not need to explicitly return something at the end of the method body. It just returns the last thing by default. This is considered good style amongst ruby folks.

Comment: `encrypt 'z' #=> "{"` should return `'a'`. The OP's question doesn't mention spaces (or periods, commas, question marks and so on) and his/her code only references lower-case letters. I think we can safely assume that `string` is comprised entirely of lower-case letters (a word). Your code is very procedural, not making use of Ruby's powerful methods.

Comment: Agreed, it is more on the procedural side I am merely presenting an alternative way of solving the problem that uses less memory. I don't know what "powerful" methods refer to in this case and I don't know even know what "powerful" means in this context so I don't know how to address that comment. While the OP did not mention spaces in the question, his code deals with the case so I decided to as well.